# Chrome 11 complains about onmessage is not defined for worker.js in ECMAScript 5 strict mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

I recently switched all my projects to ECMAScript 5 strict mode (i.e., add `"use stricts";` at top of every JS file), however the following MDC example code works everywhere **except on Chrome 11**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers#The_JavaScript_code

The code in web workers will invoke error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: onmessage is not defined.`

I tried to use `var onmessage` as a workaround, it would work in Chrome 11 but not in Firefox 4. I shouldn't be using `var` anyway coz AFAIK `onmessage` is a global variable just like `window`, redefining it makes no sense.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please provide some code? It will be difficult to guess without a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't switch to strict mode if you don't know what it means. For one, you can't specify implicit global variables, which is your problem. Specify `self.onmessage`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up using. But if it's about I should not use implicit global variables, why doesn't strict mode also throw error at `postMessage()`?

Comment: You can use global variables all you want, you just can't *specify* / *define* them *implicitly*.

Comment: I see. If so, I am kind of curious on the different behavior of browsers. Is it a bug that should be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

Then Chrome 11 is the only one who is working as the ES5 is expecting it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses

You have two possibilities:

`var onmessage = function(...`

or

`function onmessage(...`